# PHP script won't run as CRON job

Tags: php, cron

Gurus,

I have coded for my client a PHP script that performs some extensive data munging on text files he creates.

Code is complete and I have now to automate the script. Problem is that it seems to *only* run manually. I won't run as CRON job.

This is what I have tried with "#!/usr/bin/php -q" in the header of my script:

```
00 1  * * * /usr/bin/php -q /HDDLogs/HDDProcess.php >>/HDDLogs/HDDProcess.log 2>&1
```

The log file does get created but is empty. I tried removing the -q for quiet mode: no difference. Still did not run as CRON job. PHP File is chmod-ed 755.

Apache 2.0 and PHP 5.3 is installed on this server. I fully own the directory with my code and the data files are located.

In case you're wondering, my script never calls a URL.

Any idea??

Thanks,

Al.

Comment: @user484638 - remove the log file, and see it is has been re-create? If so, meaning your PHP is just yet to finsh `ps auwx | grep HDDProcess.php` to check is still running

Comment: I tried what you suggest. The log file does NOT get recreated.

Comment: @Paulo: Correct. the file HDDProcess.log is empty. I get CRON mail with an empty body (?). No message. And it is a  user crontab where I run a dozen bash scripts without problem.

Comment: Do you have any "include('foo')" with relative paths? If so you can try to write a shell script that first CD to the script directory and then calls your PHP script.

Comment: @Paulo: ((smacking myself)) You are correct!! I do have two includes with relative paths. I created a shell script wrapper that navigates into the directory before calling the script. Obrigado muito!

Comment: Same here, this was my problem. Thanks!

Comment: For reference, my cron entry is now `* 0 * * * cd /dir/containing/script; /usr/bin/php -q -f execute.php` and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be:

"`... /usr/bin/php -q -f /HDDLogs/HDDProcess.php` ..."

or

"... `/usr/bin/php -q < /HDDLogs/HDDProcess.php` ...".

Comment: Yes, you need the -f flag to execute a file from the command line. From `man php`, "-f file        Parse and execute file"

Comment: I tried both your suggestions. Does not work: php script never kicks off.

Comment: /HDDLogs/HDDProcess.log is empty? Any cron mail at inbox? The script runs when you "su" to the cronjob owner? Is it the system crontab at /etc/crontab or a user crontab?